# Calculate average days a ticket took to complete based on priority

Tags: dax

As shown in the excel file ([download here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jdlKnydYu9mVJ30pQmnap_xtr3fXu4y4N2qE2McL8EY/edit?usp=sharing)), I need to find average days based on the priority (priority) for closed tickets(status). The average days should be calculated for last 2 monthly only.

I am able to calculate the days of each ticket using the following measure.

**Measure  = Averagex(tickets,datediff(tickets[start date], tickets[complete date], day)).**[image]

Need help to figure out how to find the average days based on priority.

The end result should be like:

Priority   Ticket Count   Average-Days

Comment: How do I know that link isn't malicious?

Comment: valid question ... :) ... but link not malicious .. direct link to google sheets.

Comment: I have just uploaded the screenshot of the sheet.

Comment: you have 2 different table names: tickets, Issues! Is that correct?

Comment: oh sorry ... let's take it as tickets only ... skip issues

Comment: Also please edit C12 cell in your file. Month value is missing (20//2022)

Comment: Thank you Ozan  ... I have updated C12.

Comment: Ticket Count Measure is True ? (2,2,2)? how did you reach those numbers? Which filters?

Comment: Sorry for late reply ... Those numbers are just for demo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249265/discussion-between-kmax01-and-ozan-sen).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

CALCULATE(
AVERAGEX(tickets, tickets[complete date] - tickets[start date] ),
DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], MAX('Calendar'[Date]), -3, MONTH)
)

In case, there is already a calculated column that calculates days for each ticket, the following measure can also do the same.

CALCULATE(
AVERAGEX(tickets, tickets[col-days] ),
DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], MAX('Calendar'[Date]), -3, MONTH)
)